# Is there an easy way to reference ids using a collection's keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I have a page set up such that on load, it loads divs with ids for each individual username present in the data. They each have a bunch of messages that are supposed to emulate tweets and which are supposed to be organized under each username's div. Is there a way of easily creating divs which are stored within the original divs by using a collection which has an array of messages stored under the keys of their name (e.g. neimanmarx: array[12] is what one item looks like in this structure).
My guess is a for loop but then I don't know how to write the jquery to target the specific divs like

```
for(var x  = 0; x < thiscollection.length; x++){
  $('#'+x).append(//new div markup//);
}
```

unless that would work?

EDIT:  I should've been more clear. 
I'm taking from an object: Object {sean: Array[1], max: Array[2], ken: Array[2], samantha: Array[6]};
Each array contains objects which have message, created_at, and user properties.

I should probably draw this out. SOF obviously doesn't deem my question admissible to its exquisite forum.

Comment: Question is kind of confusing, would help if you could show data that is being loaded. What is thiscollection. Where is the main div.

Comment: Okay, I should've been more clear. I'm taking from an object:

    Object {sean: Array[1], max: Array[2], ken: Array[2], samantha: Array[6]}

Each array contains objects which have message, created_at, and user properties.

Comment: where are user ids in the array. right now it looks like this: ` { name : [ {..msg..}, {..msg..}....], name : [ {..msg..}, {..msg..}....] }`

Comment: if  you are talking about index, then your code above will work with minor change. `appendTo` instead of append.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var mainDiv = $('#mainDiv');
for(var x  = 0; x < thiscollection.length; x++){
  var ele = $('<div id = "tweet-'+x+'">');
  ele.html(//new div markup//);
  mainDiv.append(ele);
}
```